# Get local user by SID

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, permissions, directoryservices

Question: I want to get a local windows user **by SID**:

I found this code

```
[ADSI]("WinNT://$Env:Computername/<SID=S-1-5-18>")
```

here:
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32882679/add-builtin-account-to-local-group-using-winnt-adsi-provider.aspx

I deduced from it, I could do it in (VB) .NET with this:

```
Dim strURL As String = "WinNT://" + strComputerName + "/<SID=" + strSID + ">"
Dim de As DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(strURL)
de.Properties("whatever").Value.ToString()
```

However, this doesn't work.
Anybody knows how I can do this **WITHOUT** looping over all users (which requires to convert from byte[] to string first, and then compare [case insensitive] a lot of strings, which makes it slow).

Answer (score 3):

If you're on .NET 3.5 or newer, you can use this code (after adding a reference to the new `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace to your project):

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

// create a machine-context (local machine)
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);

UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Sid, <YourSidHere>);

if (up != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You've found: {0}", up.DisplayName);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: no one found");
}
```

Comment: I'm on .NET 2.0, besides, I already have the code to get the NTaccount.

Answer (score 0):

Win32 has the LookupAccountSid function, which does exactly this.

See [PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/LookupAccountSid.html) for how to use from VB.NET. In your case, the domain name will be the local computer name.

Comment: Nope, DirectoryServices, not pinvoke. Besides, I can get the NTaccount in managed code if I want to.